# Laravel delete image from array list

Tags: arrays, laravel, image, delete-row

i have database column `images` in Laravel, which contains list of images  like below `["f3bd5ad57c8389a8a1a541a76be463bf.png","37aa5dfc44dddd0d19d4311e2c7a0240.jpg","e287f0b2e730059c55d97fa92649f4f2.jpg"]`  now user wants to delete **f3bd5ad57c8389a8a1a541a76be463bf.png** i can delete image from path but i want to delete this image from the array list too. for deleting from path i can used

```
            $path=$request->picloc;
            $image_path = public_path($path);
                if (file_exists($image_path)) {
                        File::delete($image_path);
                        // delete from database too
                        return response('file deleted');
                }
```

how can i achieve that in Laravel? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert your images `array` to a [`collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections), you can use the either the [`filter`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-filter) or [`reject`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-reject) methods to remove the desired element.

Using `reject`:

```
$images = [
    "f3bd5ad57c8389a8a1a541a76be463bf.png",
    "37aa5dfc44dddd0d19d4311e2c7a0240.jpg",
    "e287f0b2e730059c55d97fa92649f4f2.jpg"
    ];

$imagesToRemove = ['f3bd5ad57c8389a8a1a541a76be463bf.png'];

$collection = collect($images)->reject(function ($value) use ($imagesToRemove) {
    return in_array($value, $imagesToRemove);
});

dd($collection);
```

Using `filter`:

```
$images = [
    "f3bd5ad57c8389a8a1a541a76be463bf.png",
    "37aa5dfc44dddd0d19d4311e2c7a0240.jpg",
    "e287f0b2e730059c55d97fa92649f4f2.jpg"
    ];

$imagesToRemove = ['f3bd5ad57c8389a8a1a541a76be463bf.png'];

$collection = collect($images)->filter(function ($value) use ($imagesToRemove) {
    return !in_array($value, $imagesToRemove);
});

dd($collection);
```

Both achieve the same outcome.